# WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips - Change width of billing and shipping details in an invoice template

Tags: wordpress, pdf, woocommerce, invoice, invoices

I would like to increase a width of billing address space in a PDF invoice template. There are cases where billing details are quite long, therefore, information is separated into two lines, I would like to avoid that.

I am using WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips Premium Templates plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done directly in the template, or by changing the CSS (it's 30% by default):

```
.invoice .shipping-address {
        width: 40%;
}

.packing-slip .billing-address {
        width: 40%;
}
```